# Blockfrost policy/metadata api issues

Tags: blockfrost

I am trying to get the metadata for the policy ID
but every Blockfrost gives error saying "invalid path"

I am able to get data related to assest using:
"https://cardano-preprod.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/2a384dc205a97463577fc98b704b537f680c0eba84126eb7d5857c865050424c32303233796f75726561636865645261686174"

but I am not able to get any information for this policy ID: 2a384dc205a97463577fc98b704b537f680c0eba84126eb7d5857c86

and when I used https://cardano-preprod.blockfrost.io/api/v0/metadata/txs/labels/721
i could not find the required metadata with policy ID: 2a384dc205a97463577fc98b704b537f680c0eba84126eb7d5857c86

HOW DO I ACCESS METADATA (721) FOR POLICY ID: 2a384dc205a97463577fc98b704b537f680c0eba84126eb7d5857c86
there are around 15 object expected to be return form this policy ID

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of assets with specific policy ID, use the `/assets/policy` endpoint.

For your example, it is https://cardano-preprod.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/policy/2a384dc205a97463577fc98b704b537f680c0eba84126eb7d5857c86.

Comment: this will get me the list of assets for that policy id, how do I get the metadata for those policy id.

Comment: policy id doesn't have metadata, only assets might have in this case